# How to dispatch to the main thread while running a coroutine test which uses background execution?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am lost in Kotlin coroutines, so I need some guidance. This are my requirements for my test which uses coroutines:

- It must have some way of blocking. I use a `delay` method to wait for responses with a timeout.
- Some part of the code *must* run on the main thread.
- Some part of the code *must* *dispatch* code **to** to main thread (this is because it is executed on a background thread).

Everything I tried has at least 1 problem. This is what I tried:

**Making my code use `runBlocking`**. This will deadlock when trying to dispatch to the main thread with this code:

```
@Test
fun testX() = runBlocking {
    var x = false
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        // This is never reached
        x = true
    }, 0)

    delay(1000)

    assert(x)
}
```

**Dispatch only the main thread for code which needs to run on the main thread**. This deadlocks right away and I don't know why:

```
@Test
fun test() = runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
    launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        // It will never reach this
    }.join()
}
```

Comment: Don't really get what you're asking... Unit tests are running on your local machine, not an Android device. So I suspect those test are running on whatever dedicated thread but Android's main... Moreover, speaking of unit tests, it isn't clear what "unit" you're trying to test.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you write unit tests, you don't have to use any classes from the Android SDK.

Regarding your question, you should set the Main dispatcher in the @Before method in order to inform the Coroutines library about what the Main is.

Here's the working code:

```
private val testDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()

@Before
fun setUp() {
    Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
}

@Test
fun test() = runTest {
    var x = false
    async(Dispatchers.Main) {
        delay(1000L)
        x = true
    }.await()

    assert(x)
}
```

Comment: This blocks, and like I mentioned in my question: I need use `delay`, also on the main thread:
        `withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            delay(1)
            x = true
        }`

Comment: Sorry, I could wrongly interpret your question. Check my updated answer please.